# SSH executes the command differently

Tags: command-line, networking, ssh, environment-variables, makefile

After several experiments I got to a surprising behavior by SSH. I usually access to a specific application through an SSH connection. In fact, that app is on a virtual-box on a workstation in a LAB. I use my laptop to connect to the app through ssh. The connection between virtual-box which provides ubuntu as the guest OS and workstation (which is ubuntu also) is defined by Bridging. 
My other method of connection to the workstation and app is through Teamviewer. Anyway, the fact is that when I run a specific command, which is execution of a make file,through TeamViewer (Remote Desktop) everything is fine and that command returns successfully, It is equal to the situation that someone runs the app locally.
But when I get to the app through SSH, the "make command" ends with several errors. It is strange that the same command has different results when it is executed through different methods!

Could you please help me how to deal with this problem. I am more comfortable to work with the shell by ssh not by teamviewer due to high bandwidth usage and delays on passing commands. To provide you with more details output of "env" command in both environments (SSH and Teamviewer) are as follows:

```
LC_PAPER=it_IT.UTF-8
XDG_SESSION_ID=7
LC_ADDRESS=it_IT.UTF-8
LC_MONETARY=it_IT.UTF-8
TERM=xterm-256color
SHELL=/bin/bash
ALTERAOCLSDKROOT=/home/legup/altera/15.0/hld
SSH_CLIENT=10.48.44.137 35604 22
LC_NUMERIC=it_IT.UTF-8
QSYS_ROOTDIR=/home/legup/altera/15.0/quartus/sopc_builder/bin
SSH_TTY=/dev/pts/10
USER=legup
LS_COLORS=rs=0:di=01;34:ln=01;36:mh=00:pi=40;33:so=01;35:do=01;35:bd=40;33;01:cd=40;33;01:or=40;31;01:su=37;41:sg=30;43:ca=30;41:tw=30;42:ow=34;42:st=37;44:ex=01;32:*.tar=01;31:*.tgz=01;31:*.arj=01;31:*.taz=01;31:*.lzh=01;31:*.lzma=01;31:*.tlz=01;31:*.txz=01;31:*.zip=01;31:*.z=01;31:*.Z=01;31:*.dz=01;31:*.gz=01;31:*.lz=01;31:*.xz=01;31:*.bz2=01;31:*.bz=01;31:*.tbz=01;31:*.tbz2=01;31:*.tz=01;31:*.deb=01;31:*.rpm=01;31:*.jar=01;31:*.war=01;31:*.ear=01;31:*.sar=01;31:*.rar=01;31:*.ace=01;31:*.zoo=01;31:*.cpio=01;31:*.7z=01;31:*.rz=01;31:*.jpg=01;35:*.jpeg=01;35:*.gif=01;35:*.bmp=01;35:*.pbm=01;35:*.pgm=01;35:*.ppm=01;35:*.tga=01;35:*.xbm=01;35:*.xpm=01;35:*.tif=01;35:*.tiff=01;35:*.png=01;35:*.svg=01;35:*.svgz=01;35:*.mng=01;35:*.pcx=01;35:*.mov=01;35:*.mpg=01;35:*.mpeg=01;35:*.m2v=01;35:*.mkv=01;35:*.webm=01;35:*.ogm=01;35:*.mp4=01;35:*.m4v=01;35:*.mp4v=01;35:*.vob=01;35:*.qt=01;35:*.nuv=01;35:*.wmv=01;35:*.asf=01;35:*.rm=01;35:*.rmvb=01;35:*.flc=01;35:*.avi=01;35:*.fli=01;35:*.flv=01;35:*.gl=01;35:*.dl=01;35:*.xcf=01;35:*.xwd=01;35:*.yuv=01;35:*.cgm=01;35:*.emf=01;35:*.axv=01;35:*.anx=01;35:*.ogv=01;35:*.ogx=01;35:*.aac=00;36:*.au=00;36:*.flac=00;36:*.mid=00;36:*.midi=00;36:*.mka=00;36:*.mp3=00;36:*.mpc=00;36:*.ogg=00;36:*.ra=00;36:*.wav=00;36:*.axa=00;36:*.oga=00;36:*.spx=00;36:*.xspf=00;36:
LC_TELEPHONE=it_IT.UTF-8
QUARTUS_ROOTDIR=/home/legup/altera/15.0/quartus/
MAIL=/var/mail/legup
PATH=/home/legup/legup-4.0/gui/scheduleviewer:/home/legup/clang+llvm-3.5.0-x86_64-linux-gnu/bin:/home/legup/altera/15.0/modelsim_ase/bin:/home/legup/altera/15.0/quartus/sopc_builder/bin:/home/legup/altera/15.0/quartus/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games
QT_QPA_PLATFORMTHEME=appmenu-qt5
LC_IDENTIFICATION=it_IT.UTF-8
PWD=/home/legup/legup-4.0
LANG=en_CA.UTF-8
LC_MEASUREMENT=it_IT.UTF-8
LEGUP_EXAMPLES=/home/legup/legup-4.0/examples
QUARTUS_64BIT=1
SHLVL=1
HOME=/home/legup
LANGUAGE=en_CA:en
LOGNAME=legup
SSH_CONNECTION=10.48.44.137 35604 10.79.4.173 22
LESSOPEN=| /usr/bin/lesspipe %s
XDG_RUNTIME_DIR=/run/user/1000
LESSCLOSE=/usr/bin/lesspipe %s %s
LC_TIME=it_IT.UTF-8
LC_NAME=it_IT.UTF-8
_=/usr/bin/env
OLDPWD=/home/legup
```

---

```
XDG_VTNR=7
XDG_SESSION_ID=c1
CLUTTER_IM_MODULE=xim
SELINUX_INIT=YES
XDG_GREETER_DATA_DIR=/var/lib/lightdm-data/legup
SESSION=ubuntu
GPG_AGENT_INFO=/run/user/1000/keyring-A53H7K/gpg:0:1
TERM=xterm
SHELL=/bin/bash
XDG_MENU_PREFIX=gnome-
VTE_VERSION=3409
ALTERAOCLSDKROOT=/home/legup/altera/15.0/hld
WINDOWID=69206027
OLDPWD=/home/legup/legup-4.0/examples
UPSTART_SESSION=unix:abstract=/com/ubuntu/upstart-session/1000/1362
QSYS_ROOTDIR=/home/legup/altera/15.0/quartus/sopc_builder/bin
GNOME_KEYRING_CONTROL=/run/user/1000/keyring-A53H7K
GTK_MODULES=overlay-scrollbar:unity-gtk-module
USER=legup
LS_COLORS=rs=0:di=01;34:ln=01;36:mh=00:pi=40;33:so=01;35:do=01;35:bd=40;33;01:cd=40;33;01:or=40;31;01:su=37;41:sg=30;43:ca=30;41:tw=30;42:ow=34;42:st=37;44:ex=01;32:*.tar=01;31:*.tgz=01;31:*.arj=01;31:*.taz=01;31:*.lzh=01;31:*.lzma=01;31:*.tlz=01;31:*.txz=01;31:*.zip=01;31:*.z=01;31:*.Z=01;31:*.dz=01;31:*.gz=01;31:*.lz=01;31:*.xz=01;31:*.bz2=01;31:*.bz=01;31:*.tbz=01;31:*.tbz2=01;31:*.tz=01;31:*.deb=01;31:*.rpm=01;31:*.jar=01;31:*.war=01;31:*.ear=01;31:*.sar=01;31:*.rar=01;31:*.ace=01;31:*.zoo=01;31:*.cpio=01;31:*.7z=01;31:*.rz=01;31:*.jpg=01;35:*.jpeg=01;35:*.gif=01;35:*.bmp=01;35:*.pbm=01;35:*.pgm=01;35:*.ppm=01;35:*.tga=01;35:*.xbm=01;35:*.xpm=01;35:*.tif=01;35:*.tiff=01;35:*.png=01;35:*.svg=01;35:*.svgz=01;35:*.mng=01;35:*.pcx=01;35:*.mov=01;35:*.mpg=01;35:*.mpeg=01;35:*.m2v=01;35:*.mkv=01;35:*.webm=01;35:*.ogm=01;35:*.mp4=01;35:*.m4v=01;35:*.mp4v=01;35:*.vob=01;35:*.qt=01;35:*.nuv=01;35:*.wmv=01;35:*.asf=01;35:*.rm=01;35:*.rmvb=01;35:*.flc=01;35:*.avi=01;35:*.fli=01;35:*.flv=01;35:*.gl=01;35:*.dl=01;35:*.xcf=01;35:*.xwd=01;35:*.yuv=01;35:*.cgm=01;35:*.emf=01;35:*.axv=01;35:*.anx=01;35:*.ogv=01;35:*.ogx=01;35:*.aac=00;36:*.au=00;36:*.flac=00;36:*.mid=00;36:*.midi=00;36:*.mka=00;36:*.mp3=00;36:*.mpc=00;36:*.ogg=00;36:*.ra=00;36:*.wav=00;36:*.axa=00;36:*.oga=00;36:*.spx=00;36:*.xspf=00;36:
XDG_SESSION_PATH=/org/freedesktop/DisplayManager/Session0
XDG_SEAT_PATH=/org/freedesktop/DisplayManager/Seat0
SSH_AUTH_SOCK=/run/user/1000/keyring-A53H7K/ssh
DEFAULTS_PATH=/usr/share/gconf/ubuntu.default.path
SESSION_MANAGER=local/legup-vm:@/tmp/.ICE-unix/1665,unix/legup-vm:/tmp/.ICE-unix/1665
XDG_CONFIG_DIRS=/etc/xdg/xdg-ubuntu:/usr/share/upstart/xdg:/etc/xdg
QUARTUS_ROOTDIR=/home/legup/altera/15.0/quartus/
PATH=/home/legup/legup-4.0/gui/scheduleviewer:/home/legup/clang+llvm-3.5.0-x86_64-linux-gnu/bin:/home/legup/altera/15.0/modelsim_ase/bin:/home/legup/altera/15.0/quartus/sopc_builder/bin:/home/legup/altera/15.0/quartus/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games
DESKTOP_SESSION=ubuntu
QT_IM_MODULE=ibus
QT_QPA_PLATFORMTHEME=appmenu-qt5
JOB=dbus
PWD=/home/legup/legup-4.0/examples/matrixmultiply
XMODIFIERS=@im=ibus
GNOME_KEYRING_PID=1605
LANG=en_CA.UTF-8
GDM_LANG=en_CA
MANDATORY_PATH=/usr/share/gconf/ubuntu.mandatory.path
LEGUP_EXAMPLES=/home/legup/legup-4.0/examples
QUARTUS_64BIT=1
IM_CONFIG_PHASE=1
COMPIZ_CONFIG_PROFILE=ubuntu
GDMSESSION=ubuntu
SESSIONTYPE=gnome-session
XDG_SEAT=seat0
HOME=/home/legup
SHLVL=1
LANGUAGE=en_CA:en
GNOME_DESKTOP_SESSION_ID=this-is-deprecated
LOGNAME=legup
COMPIZ_BIN_PATH=/usr/bin/
XDG_DATA_DIRS=/usr/share/ubuntu:/usr/share/gnome:/usr/local/share/:/usr/share/
QT4_IM_MODULE=xim
DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS=unix:abstract=/tmp/dbus-fzhVmN3W5R
LESSOPEN=| /usr/bin/lesspipe %s
INSTANCE=
TEXTDOMAIN=im-config
XDG_RUNTIME_DIR=/run/user/1000
DISPLAY=:0
XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP=Unity
GTK_IM_MODULE=ibus
LESSCLOSE=/usr/bin/lesspipe %s %s
TEXTDOMAINDIR=/usr/share/locale/
COLORTERM=gnome-terminal
XAUTHORITY=/home/legup/.Xauthority
_=/usr/bin/env
```

---

[Ouput of makefile when executed by ssh](https://www.dropbox.com/s/lhzklk7mryb8vtl/make_output.txt?dl=0)

Comment: And the question is? And the command is? And the methods are?

Comment: @Jakuje The question is why my command returns different outputs using either ssh or teamviewer. the command is "make hybrid" it is a make command for an app called Legup which is about high level synthesis. The methods are SSH or Opening the terminal using TeamViewer. The command ends with many errors when it is executed by ssh.

Comment: You should also provide the actual output of `make`.

Comment: I have no idea how teamviewer sets terminal, nor what env variables are needed for your HLS tool. Without any actual error, it is impossible to guess as @muru noted.

Comment: @Jakuje TeamViewer does not set the terminal. Using TeamViewer I make  a remote desktop connection to the workstation, then I open the virtual box and then open the terminal inside that as if I am working with the terminal locally. I will add the output of make :-)

Comment: So then it will be some problem of your login scripts/startup scripts which sets up some variables only for local login. Only thing I miss is gnome-keyring (and DISPLAY, if you need X11, but I guess not), but it should not matter for your make.

Comment: @muru Here it is the link to make output : https://www.dropbox.com/s/lhzklk7mryb8vtl/make_output.txt?dl=0

Comment: @Jakuje The make output : https://www.dropbox.com/s/lhzklk7mryb8vtl/make_output.txt?dl=0

Comment: So perl does not like your Italian Locale as far as I see ...  try to comment out the line `SendEnv LANG LC_*` in your local `/etc/ssh/ssh_config`, reconnect and try again.

Comment: @Jakuje Yesss! It solved the problem. could you please write an answer for this question so that I can select it as the best answer. Moreover, I am curious about how could you pin point the exact problem via the information that I put here. I would appreciate your detailed explanations :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the transcript output from your `make` command, you should notice the important part:

```
perl: warning: Setting locale failed.
perl: warning: Please check that your locale settings:
    LANGUAGE = "en_CA:en",
    LC_ALL = (unset),
    LC_PAPER = "it_IT.UTF-8",
    LC_ADDRESS = "it_IT.UTF-8",
    LC_MONETARY = "it_IT.UTF-8",
    LC_NUMERIC = "it_IT.UTF-8",
    LC_TELEPHONE = "it_IT.UTF-8",
    LC_IDENTIFICATION = "it_IT.UTF-8",
    LC_MEASUREMENT = "it_IT.UTF-8",
    LC_TIME = "it_IT.UTF-8",
    LC_NAME = "it_IT.UTF-8",
    LANG = "en_CA.UTF-8"
    are supported and installed on your system.
perl: warning: Falling back to the standard locale ("C").
```

This is the difference between local login and remote, because `ssh` is passing `LC_*` environmental variables through in default instalations. It sounds like a good idea to show you the environment in the your locale, but it usually does not work and causes more trouble.

There are several ways how to workaround this problem. My favorite is to modify local ssh client configuration in `/etc/ssh/ssh_config` and comment out the line and reconnect:

```
# SendEnv LANG LC_*
```

You can do the same also on the server side of `sshd`, but the file is `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` and option is called `AcceptEnv` (value is the same).

It should be also possible to install your Italian (or the `en_CA` one might be the problem?) locale to your server, but I don't see the gain here.

The root cause anyway would be the tool itself, because it looks like it is trying to parse output of some perl script and does not handle these errors correctly.

Comment: You should probably use `~/.ssh/config` instead of editing the system-wide `/etc/ssh/ssh_config`

Comment: @muru unfortunately, this option once is set globally, it is not possible to "overwrite" I other files.

Comment: Ah, it is append-only: http://superuser.com/questions/485569/how-to-disable-sendenv-variables-set-in-ssh-config-from-ssh-config